# ReferenceError: critiques is not defined in Node/Express App

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to work on the "review" part of a review/rating website. We have a mongoose Schema which I'm pushing new reviews to.

This is the schema:

```
var WorkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    workType: String,
    length: Number,
    ageRange: String,
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    },
    manuscriptText: String,
    critiques: [
        {
            reviewerName: String,
            critique: String,
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }
    ],
    ratingNumber: [Number],
    ratingSum: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

When a user submits a new review, this is the post route. It is pushing the critique to the array of critiques associated to the work (confirmed by searching in mongodb), but I keep getting a reference error that "critique" is not defined in the render. I need to re-render the work page so that the reviewer can see that their critique has been added and displays on the front end. Not sure why this is happening since 'critiques' is practically everywhere.

```
router.post('/:id', function(req, res) {

    Work.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
        {
            $push: 
                {
                    critiques: {
                        reviewerName: req.user.username,
                        critique: req.body.critique
                    }
                }
        }, { new: true}).populate('works', 'critiques').exec(function(err, foundWork) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }  else {
                    res.render('work', 
                        {
                            user: foundWork, 
                            title: foundWork.title, 
                            critiques: critiques,
                            currentUser: req.user,
                            work: foundWork
                        }
                    );
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while you are rendering all the values after update.

you are doing `critiques: critiques,`

while `critiques` is not defined as a variable.

now you have 2 options , first is  you can just show the full `critiques` array. as it is coming from the database.[may be you can do some operations with that data if need.]
like `critiques: foundWork.critiques`.
or otherwise yoou can just show the data you are inserting at that time as 
`critiques : req.body.critiques`

like below:

*Take from DB as it is*

```
res.render("work", {
      user: foundWork,
      title: foundWork.title,
      critiques: foundWork.critiques,
      currentUser: req.user,
      work: foundWork
    });
```

*take from body pushing the current element*

```
res.render("work", {
      user: foundWork,
      title: foundWork.title,
      critiques: req.body.critiques,
      currentUser: req.user,
      work: foundWork
    });
```